# What is CakePHP $request->params['bare']?

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I know the origin and use of other params in the request object but what is `$request->params['bare']`use for and when is it set? .when debugging with DebugKit, I like to use request panel to inspect the entire request object and sometimes encounter it set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a parameter typically only used internally with `RequestActionTrait` (which is deprecated as of CakePHP 3.3.0, you should use [**View Cells**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/cells.html) instead).

When `true`-ish, the controller will disable `autoLayout` for rendering, ie no layout is being rendered, only the corresponding template of the requested action is.

See also

- **[GitHub > Remove all references to requestAction()](https://github.com/cakephp/docs/pull/4166/files)**
- **[Source > Controller\Controller::render()](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.3.9/src/Controller/Controller.php#L588)**
- **[Source > Routing\RequestActionTrait::requestAction()](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.3.9/src/Routing/RequestActionTrait.php#L102)**